# Limits negative infinity with cosine

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim\limits_{ x \to −\infty} \cos(x) + \dfrac x {7-2 x}$$

i tried to factor $7-2 x$ and got $-1/2+7/2(-2 x+7)$

How do i solve this? is the limit infinity?

Comment: Check this graph out: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gvtkzxehfg

Comment: so the limit doesnt exist?

Comment: This looks like an exam question. Do your exam.

Comment: its actually a homework question